# How big a sample size do I need to say a player is performing below average on penalty shots?

Tags: sample-size

An average ball player scores 20% of his penalties.

How many penalty results would I need to receive before I can say that a player scores at a rate of 15% requires coaching on his penalty shots?

How do I calculate this based on different population averages, statistical certainty etc.

Comment: Interesting question. You might also ask if a player is scoring below his/her own historical average.  In any case, how many data points do you have for each player?  How many observations go into the calculation of the average percent penalties?  Is this number constant across players?  If not, you might want to switch to number of successful penalties out of N.

Comment: @Joel W. Say you have data for the whole league, so maybe the league average for the month is 20% over 200 penalties taken. For the player you have data going back several years, so how many months back do I want to look for saying that I have enough points that if he scores below average it is not likely to just be random noise but also still look at recent results.

Comment: How many data points (penality tries) do you have for any given player for a typical year?

Comment: The actual problem I am looking at is not about a sport and I will have hundreds of data points a year to look at.

Comment: Are you interested in month to month variation? If so, how many data points will you have on each "player' each month?  How many data points do you have on each player, overall?